# Decorated names for 32-bit & 64-bit version of the same DLL

Tags: visual-c++, dll, shared-libraries, dllimport, dllexport

I'm using VC++ on VS2013.
I've been given 32bit version of a DLL "ABC.DLL", which exposes functions say Apple(), Bananna() etc..
When using these function pointers in my application App.EXE code, I do use

```
LoadLibrary("ABC.DLL");
GetProcAddress(DllHandler,"Apple@4");
GetProcAddress(DllHandler,"Bananna@8");
```

etc..

I know these are the decorated names.

I don't have the source code for ABC.DLL.

Now if I use 64bit version of the ABC.DLL in the 64-bit version of App.EXE's code, 
the same way (GetProcAddress as used above), I get "NULL" as teh return value from each of the GetProcAddress() used.
But the LoadLibrary("ABC.DLL") succeeds.

Now I'm wondering if the decorated names are different for 32-bit ABC.DLL & 64bit ABC.DLL?
How would we know ? Details would be helpful.

Comment: What does the dependency walker or DUMPBIN say?

Comment: Using dependency walker how can I see teh functions exported by the DLL ? I thought dependency walker is only for seeing the list of dependencies ? Plz correct me if I'm wrong. thanks

Comment: Dependency walker also shows the exported function names and can optionally remove the decoration. Just look in the middle panel on the right when you fire it up on a DLL.

Comment: Yes I see that using both DLLExport Viewer & dependency walker tool I'm not able to see any fuunction exposed by the ABC.DLL for 64bit DLL. But for 32-bit DLL I can see teh exported functions. Does this mean that there is some problem with the 64bit version of DLL I got ?

Comment: Well I can see 64-bit exports fine, so either you have an older version of the dependency walker (I use V2.2.6), or maybe the DLL really doesn't have any exports.

Comment: 64-bit code only has one calling convention.  So there is no need to decorate exported names, it will be plain "Apple" instead of "_Apple@4".  You will have to customize your code to account for this.

Comment: @HansPassant Surely any C++ exports *will* still be decorated?

Comment: @HansPassant :: Thanks. But when I open the 64-bit DLL in the DLL export viewer and in dependency walker, I see that it doesn't show any functions at all!! But whereas if I open the same DLL (32-bit version), I see all the exported function in both dependency welker and dll export viewer. Isn't this an indication that the 64-bit DLL is not proper ?

Comment: Not healthy of course.  Get another opinion from dumpbin.exe /exports, Depends isn't fit for the task anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant Depends works. Note that it comes in two flavors, 32-bit (x86) and 64-bit (x64). Download both. When examining a DLL, for best results use the one with matching bitness.